# Djnago-admin how to add extra Fields registrations in django-admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin, registration

In my web application, only the admin can register a user. I need to add extra fields to the registration form only in the djnago-admin interface, how can I do it, please?

Comment: it can help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/, please read carefully.

Comment: you have to override *fieldsets* and *add_fieldsets* in your UserAdmin class in admin.py

Comment: could you give me more details  please @Zilay

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding fieldsets and add_feildsets in the admin.py file.

You can check here for more information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example